# Error checking Object is null

Tags: java, eclipse, json, httpresponse, apache-httpclient-4.x

I got a HttpResponse which gets a json response.

Now if the json response contains data it all works fine, but whenever the json is null my application crashes.

I've been trying to following code but with no avail.

(sb = json response)

```
Object result11 = sb;
Log.d("Result11", result11.toString());

if (result11 == JSONObject.NULL)
    Log.d("if", "I am NULL");
else
    Log.d("else", "I am not null");
```

I tried comparing result11 to:

```
null, "", "null", JSONObject.NULL
```

It always returns "I am not null"

Whilst the log says that Resul11 = null.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
Object result11 = sb;
            Log.d("Result11", result11.toString());

            StringBuilder test = (StringBuilder)result11;

            if (test.toString().equals("null"))
                Log.d("if", "I am NULL");
            else
                Log.d("else", "I am not null");
```

SOLUTION by @Mark Byers

```
test.toString().trim().equals("null")
```

results in "I AM NULL"

Comment: What is the runtime type of `result11`? Try printing the result of `result11.getClass()`.

Comment: StringBulder class, also tried by casting the object to a string (String)result11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a `null`. You have a `StringBuilder` that when converted to a `String` contains the value `"null"`.

To compare strings do not use the `==` operator. Instead you should convert to a `String` and use the `equals` method.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = (StringBuilder)result11;
String trimmed = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
if (trimmed.equals("null")) { ... }
```

The `==` operator compares the references and only returns true if the operands are references to the same object (or both null references). The `equals` method compares the values.

**Related**

- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: Tried it but still results in not null. Also checked the webpage it reads it deffinitly says it's null, so does logcat.

Comment: I've added an explicit cast. If the type is wrong you should get an exception.

Comment: Check my edit what I changed it to.
It still results in I am not null =\ EDIT: I also added the stringbuilder to the log and results in printing null.

Comment: @Deejdd.. Seems like you have some unprintable characters or leading or trailing whitespaces in your string. Try using - `test.toString().trim().equals("null")`. This will only remove whitespaces if there are some.

Comment: Yes trimming worked ;), Marked as answer and added the solution to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

if you get a null result compare to a null pointer: `result11 == null`